# Long range two qubit gates in superconducting qubits

Tags: quantum-gate, entanglement, experimental-realization, superconducting-quantum-computing

In superconducting qubits, all the method that I have seen until now are based on short range interaction.

For example you have two qubits to process information around a middle qubit that is actually a coupler. By tuning its frequency you can make the two other qubit fictively interact.

**My question is:** Is there at least one method of performing two qubit gates in superconducting qubit that allows for long range interaction, i.e two qubit that are far on the computer can interact. Even a gate with very bad fidelity. Or nothing has been found for now on?